# How to double an image size in HTML using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have tried using
In HTML:

```
<img src="../Resources/title.png" />
```

In CSS:

```
img {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}
```

But this scales the images based on the parent tag the image is in.  If an image is 150px by 150px I want to scale it to 300px by 300px.  I want this to work for all images no matter their size or parent tag.  And I only want to use CSS.  ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't using **CSS < Version 3** only.

When you set the width/height on an element it is relative to it's container.

---

**Update**, as it's been quite some time since this answer was posted.

As a commenter points out, this can be achieved by simply using the `zoom` CSS property. However, [it's not recommended](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/), as it was first implemented solely by IE, in the IE6/7 days, and [never formalized into the W3C standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom#wikiArticle). Instead, what's commonly used nowadays is a CSS transform using the `scale` function.

More on the `scale()` CSS function: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/2n5zLhz3/

Comment: It's been a while; with CSS >= Version 3: `{ zoom: 2 }`.

Comment: Thanks mate, I was not sure about "zoom", just quickly tried it in Chrome here, so it's great you went the extra mile for the correct method!

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with the `scale()` 2D transform, but being one of the flashy new CSS3 features [support is incomplete at this time and you need vendor prefixes](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d):

```
img {
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

However I don't believe this takes into account the flow of content, as transforms are done on individual elements and as such do not affect layout. See also the [`transform-origin` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-origin-property).

If you need good browser support, or you need the content to reflow properly, you'll have to make do with an alternative such as using JavaScript or restructuring your HTML, such that the `width` and `height` properties will scale it correctly and affect element flow in a natural way.

Answer (score 3):

You can enclose the image in a *div* and then set its size relative to the parent.

```
<style type="text/css">
.double{
  display: inline-block;
}

.double img{
  width: 200%;
}
</style>
<div class="double"><img src="../Resources/title.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use min-width property on your image to force your width to be larger than its parent div, e.g.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  min-width: 200%;
  /* center image */
  margin-left: -50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bc/Information_example_page_300px.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can double the image by taking the percent you need from window size.

```
p > img {
  width:100%;
  height:60vh;
}
```

"height:100vh;" means 100% from your browsing window.Just have to do the math.

Answer (score 0):

Use the width 110%, because it is in a div and there was extra space.

```
img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 110%;
}
```